# Webhook handling with PHP

Tags: php, webhooks

I'm trying to build a webhook receiver.

I created this simple PHP-Script and uploaded it to my webhost:

```
$raw_payload = file_get_contents('php://input', true);
$payload = json_decode($raw_payload, true);

if($payload){
  $myfile = fopen("log.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
  fwrite(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()).PHP_EOL);
  fclose($myfile);
}
```

then, in the App who sends the Webhook (actually Wekan) I entered the URL to the file:

> http://myurl.com/dir/receiver.php

I sent some webhooks then, but nothing is written into the file.
The webhooks were sent correctly (I tested it with a webhook-tester and received some correct data there but not in my php-file).

The webhook data wich should be send looks like this (JSON):

```
{
  text: '{{wekan-username}} moved "{{card-title}}" from "{{old-list-name}}" to "{{new-list-name}}"\nhttp://{{wekan-host}}/b/{{board-id}}/{{board-name}}/{{card-id}}',
  cardId: '{{card-id}}',
  listId: '{{new-list-id}}',
  oldListId: '{{old-list-id}}',
  boardId: '{{board-id}}',
  user: '{{wekan-username}}',
  card: '{{card-title}}',
  description: 'act-moveCard'
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? (Can it be a problem with my webhost? The webhook-tester uses https, but for my php-file Im using http, does this cause the error?)

Comment: What do your web server logs say? Was the request received? What was PHP's response code? Did the error log log anything?

Comment: _Suggestion:_ You can simplify your logging with just `file_put_contents('log.txt', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()).PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);`

Comment: Uhh someone was in a bad mood here... As I wrote the log.txt is empty => desired behaviour => something is in the log.txt. Also my script is on a shared server webhosting package => I don't have the chance to see into my webserver logs... (I watched similar questions, no logs posted there and no votes for hold). Also I can't see the POSt request in the Browser-Dev-Tools, BUT as I wrote at least on webhook.site (webhook-tester) I receiver correct data. I thought this would be a minor problem in my code (it wasnt the $filehandle, thats a typo here not in the code sorry for that)

Answer (score 3):

Your not passing the file resource handle to [fwrite()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php).

Then perhaps make your code more verbose, and keep an eye on the error log:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $raw_payload = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $payload = json_decode($raw_payload, true);

    if (is_array($payload)) {
        $fh = fopen("log.txt", "a+");

        if ($fh) {
            fwrite($fh, date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()).PHP_EOL);
            fclose($fh);
        } else {
            trigger_error("Unable to open file!");
        }
    } else {
        trigger_error("Invalid payload!");
    }
} else {
    trigger_error("Invalid request!");
}
```

Comment: Wasn't me, but voted you up again, but that was not the solution, still the log.txt stays empty. Thanks to Mr. deceze this is on hold now, I'll try to move my code on a different machine where I can access the serverlogs. So it seems that its not the code itself (I copyed yours) wich creates the problem but maybe my shared hosting package or something different.

Comment: You might want to just check with [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) that you can send a request to it and leave it where it is so you know its the host which is the issue. *webhook.site* wont work in your case as its testing the service which sends the payload not your endpoint. From what I've seen most hosts offer logs even the free ones, though sometimes combined. If not you should definitely look for a host which does. Also you can use tools like https://ngrok.com to dev locally with an accessible url which you can inspect the traffic, its very handy for building callback apis